# How can I make a triangle in HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to use basic CSS to make triangle in an HTML page. I am using triangle pics which take time to load, so, I want to decrease loading time of my page.

Comment: To understand how this shape works and for alternative solutions please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/1811992

Answer (score 35):

Not possible with HTML, but with CSS. Example:

```
<div class="triangle></div>
```

```css
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GR4Kj/)**

- `30px` in the `border` property defines the size: width and height. You can change it if you want a smaller or a bigger triangle.
- if you want to rotate the triangle, switch the position of `black` and `transparent` in the `border-color` property. See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GR4Kj/2/)**

Comment: Note that by leaving two borders on, you get right triangles instead, which allow you to generate any triangle you need. See my answer and http://jsfiddle.net/GR4Kj/5/  http://www.uselesspickles.com/triangles/

Answer (score 24):

This is the best explanation on how to create CSS triangles: http://www.uselesspickles.com/triangles/

By creating divs without width or height, the borders end up creating a triangle when you leave some of the borders as transparent.

**Credit** That page was written by a co-worker, way before other people figured out this trick.

```css
#tri {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top-width: 20px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-width: 20px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tri"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zEuL/)**

Answer (score 8):

This will make a triangle

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <polygon points="50, 50, 100, 100, 0, 100" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick behind making a css triangle is

1. Create an empty `div`
2. Make its height and width 0.
3. Give 2 opposite sides same border-width and make them transparent.
4. Give the third one same border-width, give it a solid color.

Hope this helps.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdtareque/mUaq4/1/)

Comment: Doesn't work. Unless you missed a step in your explanation. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUaq4/).

Comment: Thanks updated !!! Please update if you can explain it or have some other idea/trick for the same.